# Video Editing: Unable to create Keyframe

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video, keyframes

I've imported a long MOV file (50 mins, x264) and I want to do some speed control over it.

I deleted the audio track to focus just on the video track.

I have dope sheet and graph editor open too.

In the Sequencer View, I <kbd>right-click</kbd> on the track and <kbd>left-click</kbd> to a specific frame. I press <kbd>I</kbd> and nothing appears in the dope sheet, the timeline or the graph editor at all.

So, I create a strip (speed) and <kbd>right-click</kbd> on it and - as shown in the official docs - untick *Stretch Input* where I expect the *Speed Factor* box to show the current frame.

It does not. I press <kbd>I</kbd>, nothing happens.

Please help.

Comment: Are you pressing `I` over the strip? or over the values on the properties region? You need to keyframe the values. Does [this help](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/26919/935)?

Comment: Ah I can keyframe the speed factor, but not the frame it appears. I will use then this, thanks.